# No event is fired when putting spring security login form inside angularjs ngview

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

I am trying to customize and mix angularjs application based on [this example](https://github.com/ystarikovich/SimpleWebApp) and spring security. On my index page, i inserted the spring security login form (before the ngview) and it works perfectly but when i tryed to move that form to a separated html page that is called by the ngview theare is no action fired and i can not get the login form work, so any help or suggestion please and thank you in advance.

Comment: You'll need to do some more debugging check with the network inspector what is loaded into the view can also use the 'debugger;' keyword in Js to trigger a breakpoint.  Also check the console for errors need more details about the particular problem.

Comment: there is no action catched with the network inspector, there is no error in the console ( no action is fired ), i am thinking about working with two modules (a dedicated one for the login form)